# Diagnosing sporadic crashes on debian jessie (stable)

Tags: linux, debian, crash

My server used to be incredibly stable on wheezy. After upgrading to jessie, it is now prone to crashing about once per week.

I check on my server in the morning, the machine is on and the screen is lit up but shows only solid black. Moving the mouse, typing on the keyboard, and trying to switch to a different TTY all have no noticeable effect. The machine is also not reachable via ssh on my lan. I have looked through every single log in /var/log and there are zero suspicious entries.

It could be a hardware issue (it's a laptop, has an ssd, built-in wifi, and has drivers from non-free repo), but since it began happening exactly when I upgraded to jessie, I would find that a little too coincidental.

**Question**: How can I diagnose whether or not it is a hardware or software problem, and which component is the offender? You may assume I have root access to the machine.

Comment: any update? I'm having the same issue except 3-4x a day.

Comment: No update, problem persist, can't find anyone who will help :(